# django-tinymce changes relative urls

Tags: javascript, python, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

tinymce to manage my contents. it's ok, works but there is a small thing that i a curious to know is that why tinymce changes urls by it's own. for example:

i put a link and using url like `/post/post1`
but whenever i check my url, tinymce makes it like: `../../../../../post/post1`
however, it's ok and does not break my link, but that feels bad to see!
this also happens for images

Django:3.2.12

django-tinymce: 3.4.0

tinymce (by it's own): TinyMCE 5.10.1

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to `tinymce.init` - `convert_urls: false`